How to use user input as parameter name?
I want to ask the user to choose one parameter and then based on the user's input make some operations on the chosen parameter. How can I do it in Java?
for example:
List A = new List();
List B = new List();
String userInput = in.nextLine(); //here the user chooses which list he wants to do the operations on

I want to take user input (which will be a String with A or B in it) and do the operations on it.
I used switch but the code is not efficient that way in case I'll have more than just 2 Lists in the future.

Use a Map<String, List> instead of single variables. And parametrize those Lists, while you're at it.

To make a code more efficient you should handle errors from the user input.

You want to have a Map of String : List and then you can retrieve the desired List.
// Making the map and adding items to it
Map<String, List<String>> listMap = new HashMap<>();

List<String> A = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> B = new ArrayList<>();

listMap.put("A", A);
listMap.put("B", B);

// Retrieving wanted list from map
String userInput = in.nextLine();
List<String> userList = map.get(userInput);

doSomething(userList);


Just another concept utilizing User Input Validation. Read the comments in code:
/* Open a keyboard input stream. The JVM will auto-close 
   this stream when the application closes:        */
final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
// OS newline character sequence.
final String NL = System.lineSeparator();

// Using `LinkedHashMap` so to ensure insertion order:
java.util.LinkedHashMap<String, java.util.List<String>> listMap = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();

/* Create a few Lists for testing. Create as many Lists as you
   like but be sure to apply them to the LinkedHashMap:      */
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("List A: Value1", "List A: Value2");
List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("List B: Value1", "List B: Value2");
List<String> listC = Arrays.asList("List C: Value1", "List C: Value2");

// Add Lists to LinkedHashMap:
listMap.put("A", listA);
listMap.put("B", listB);
listMap.put("C", listC);

// Create a `Set` containing all the LinkedHashMap keys: 
java.util.Set<String> keys = listMap.keySet();

/* Build the menu based on what is in the LinkedHashMap for keys.
   The menu selection will not be letter case sensitive:     */
StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder("");
// Prompt Info:
menu.append("Select the desired List to work with:").append(NL);

// Used for building validation regex. 
StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("["); 
    
// Iterate through the `Set` of keys:
for (String key : keys) {
    regex.append(key);  // Add to regex:
    menu.append("  ").append(key).append(") List: ").append(key).append(NL); // Add to menu:
}
regex.append("]");  // Add to regex (now complete):
menu.append("  Q) Quit!").append(NL);   // Apply a quit option to menu:
menu.append("Your Choice? -> ");        // Prompt (menu now complete):

// Retrieving desired list from User (with validation):
String choice = "";
while (choice.isEmpty()) {
    // Display menu:
    System.out.print(menu.toString());
    /* Get User Input. Also trim off any possible leading or trailing
       whitespaces, tabs, etc and, convert the input to uppercase in
       case the supplied the menu choice in lower letter case:     */
    choice = userInput.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();

    // Did User choose Quit?
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Quiting! - Bye Bye");
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise, validate User's menu choice input:
    // Is a valid menu choice entered by User?
    else if (!choice.matches(regex.toString())) {
        // NO...Inform User and allow to try again:
        System.out.println("Invalid menu choice (" + choice + ")! Try again..." + LS);
        choice = "";    // Empty `choice` to ensure re-loop:
    }
}

// Menu choice is valid...retrieve List. 
List<String> usersDesiredList = listMap.get(choice);

// Do something with `usersDesiredList`.
// Display selected List:
System.out.println(usersDesiredList);

